# mvn stops working on downloading

Tags: maven

when i try to run

```
 mvn clean install
```

(or such a command of maven)
then he starts to download the dependency.
At one dependency (one on our server) he stops and don't continue to work.
More poeple says that this can be a problem of antivirus or firewall.
I tryed to made a

```
scp address@myrepo:.....
```

and it works. This for my opinion is not a firewall problem or antivirus (I run on ubuntu, and don't have any antivirus installed)

Can some one give me some tips how figure out the problem?

Maven version 3.2.1

I have noticed this behavior: When it start the download a directory under .m2/repository/.... is created. In the directory 2 file are created:

-nameOfPom.pom.lastUpdated 
 -nameOfPom.pom.tmp4c338b26031e4cda

When I open the first file I can see:

```
Cannot connect. Reason\: java.net.ConnectException\: Connection timed out
```

An other info:

```
On the server side I see that a connection is established.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem: 
I installed the maven version 3.0.4 and now all works!

Comment: So what was the problem? A bug in latest versions of Maven?

Comment: I'm investigating. Wiht version 3.0.4 works, with 3.2.1 no. Configs are the same. I try to find out and give a feed-back

Comment: I have also the same problem with version 3.2.2. I created an issue on the jira maven.

Comment: The correct link to the issue is now: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5674

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your private/enterprise repo is configured in your local maven settings.

In the `$MAVEN_HOME/conf/settings.xml` file, you should add :

```
<settings ...>
  ...
  <servers>
    ...
    <server>
      <id>private-repo</id>
      <username>{REPO_USER}</username>
      <password>{REPO_PASS}</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
  <mirrors>
    ...
    <mirror>
      <id>private-repo</id>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <url>http://...</url>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  ...
</settings>
```

Comment: Yes I havware configured. I also tryed to put an error to see if the file was reading. When I put an error in the file, he gives me an error by connecting. When I remove the error then he hangs by the connection (hangs = more than 10min)